# How do I get my HP PHotosmart 7520 setup to scan to mac?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have my HP Photosmart wireless printer setup successfully to print from my MacBook, but cannot get the scan to PC function to work.  Help!

Comment: Are you using iPhoto? What have you tried?

Comment: which way does it not work, ie from scanner to mac or form mac to scanner

Comment: Are you trying to use the "Scan To" button on the front of the printer?  (If it has one?)  In my experience those only ever work with Windows, not with other OSs.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening Preview and choosing **File** -> **Import from Scanner**

Answer (score 1):

I have an HP ColorSmart 309g, a later model, but it is a similar general design with both inkjet printing and scanning functionality.

The only way that I have been able to get a scan from the printer to OS X other than sneakernet (i.e. scanning to a memory card or thumb drive, then plugging the card or drive into the computer and copying the files over) is through the web interface.

If your printer has a built-in web server like mine, you can visit the IP address of the printer on your local network in any web browser.  Along with diagnostics and ink level info, you should then see a button or menu for scanning.  You just put what you want to scan on the glass or into the feeder, then click the "scan" button and the scanned image appears as a web page, from which you can download it.

Comment: This was the only option for me. It seems HP on MacOSX is stuck in the past, cannot scan wirelessly whereas on Windows it's a breeze. Sometimes I feel I'm back to the 90's..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to choose and dowload the [full package from HP](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=mp-125168-2&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5199463&tmp_track_link=ot_search) depending on your OS.

> This download package contains the full software solution for OS X
>   10.9 Mavericks including all necessary software and drivers.

That should solve the problem.